# Set up Adwords conversion script in php

Tags: php, wordpress, google-ads-api

I have a registration page on WP; when the data is collected it automatically logs the person in to the site. At that point I'd like to fire the Adwords conversion script in PHP.

This is what I have at the moment but it doesn't seem to be working (obvs changed

```
// register the user using the WP function
do_action('user_register', $user_id);
            
// google script for signup
echo "<script> 
        gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-id_number'});
    </script>";
```

Is there an obvious reason why this isn't working?

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Well yes, once the use is accepted, you have to add the script on next redirected page he/she lands. So use the registration hook to check if the user has successfully registered, then append the script using wp_head hook.

Comment: Unfortunately that can't work as the redirected page is the home page for users which is hit all the time whether they're newly registered or not. I was hoping there was a way of firing this from WITHIN php code.

Comment: Well I guess it can. Your function which adds the script is added as user registration action is hit. At other times it won't hit, because the action won't be hit. And yes it is within PHP only